# Aumentar cantidad de Input

Tags: javascript

Tengo el siguiente campo para disminuir o aumentar la cantidad del mismo.

```
<span class="input-group-btn">
  <button class="btn btn-default" id="menos" type="button">-</button>
</span>

<input type="text" id="contador" value="1" min="1"/>

<span class="input-group-btn">
  <button class="btn btn-default" id="mas" type="button">+</button>
</span>
```

JS

```
var sumar = document.getElementById("mas");
var restar = document.getElementById("menos");
var contador = document.getElementById("contador");

sumar.onclick = function() {
  contador.value = Number(contador.value) + 1;
};

restar.onclick = function() {
  contador.value = Number(contador.value) - 1;
};
```

Así funciona si solo tuviera ese campo, pero como voy a agregarlos dinámicamente, la idea es que funcione para la cantidad de campos que haya.

Es decir si tuviera por ejemplo 3

```
<span class="input-group-btn">
  <button class="btn btn-default" id="menos" type="button">-</button>
</span>

<input type="text" id="contador" value="1" min="1"/>

<span class="input-group-btn">
  <button class="btn btn-default" id="mas" type="button">+</button>
</span>

<!------!>

<span class="input-group-btn">
  <button class="btn btn-default" id="menos" type="button">-</button>
</span>

<input type="text" id="contador" value="1" min="1"/>

<span class="input-group-btn">
  <button class="btn btn-default" id="mas" type="button">+</button>
</span>

<!------!>

<span class="input-group-btn">
  <button class="btn btn-default" id="menos" type="button">-</button>
</span>

<input type="text" id="contador" value="1" min="1"/>

<span class="input-group-btn">
  <button class="btn btn-default" id="mas" type="button">+</button>
</span>
```

Pero de esos 3 solo me funciona 1.

Comment: En principio solo te funciona para uno porque estas agregando el mismo **id** en todos los input, recuerda que _id_ es un identificador único y no se repite, con las clases puedes referenciar a varios elementos pero el resultado seria único, tendrás que agregar un **id único** a cada input y generar su respectiva función para cada operación, hay muchas formas de hacerlo, pero no se entiende bien el contexto de tu pregunta, editala.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo de esta manera

```
<div>
    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-default btn-restar" id="menos1" value=1 type="button">-</button>
    </span>
    
    <input type="text" id="contador1" class="contador" value="1" min="1"/>
    
    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-default btn-sumar" id="mas1" value=1 type="button">+</button>
    </span>
</div>
<div>
    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-default btn-restar" id="menos2" value=1 type="button">-</button>
    </span>
    
    <input type="text" id="contador2" class="contador" value="1" min="1"/>
    
    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-default btn-sumar" id="mas2" value=1 type="button">+</button>
    </span>
</div>
<div>
    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-default btn-restar" id="menos3" value=1 type="button">-</button>
    </span>
    
    <input type="text" id="contador3" class="contador" value="1" min="1"/>
    
    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-default btn-sumar" id="mas3" value=1 type="button">+</button>
    </span>
</div>
```

Y el código JS

```
    var elemSumar = document.getElementsByClassName("btn-sumar");
    var elemRestar = document.getElementsByClassName("btn-restar");
    var elemContador = document.getElementsByClassName("contador");

    for(let i =0; i<elemSumar.length; i++){
        elemSumar[i].addEventListener("click", ()=>sumar(elemContador[i], elemSumar[i].value));
        elemRestar[i].addEventListener("click", ()=>restar(elemContador[i], elemRestar[i].value))
    }

    function sumar(contador, value) {
        contador.value = Number(contador.value) + Number(value);
    };

    function restar(contador, value) {
        contador.value = Number(contador.value) - Number(value);
    };
```

Así solo hay que añadirle una clase para diferenciar los botones de restar de los de sumar y los contadores. Añadirle un value al botón para que sume ese valor (por si quieres añadir botones de sumar mas cantidad no hay que modificar el script) y despues añadire los listeners para los botones

Answer (score 1):

Hola yo usaria jquery para facilitar mas las cosas.

Primero cambiaria unas cosas en tu estructura de html, quitando los id por name y metiendo todo en un div.

```
    <div>
            <span class="input-group-btn">
              <button class="btn btn-default" name="menos" type="button">-</button>
            </span>
    
            <input type="text" name="contador" value="1" min="1"/>
    
            <span class="input-group-btn">
              <button class="btn btn-default" name="mas" type="button">+</button>
            </span>
</div>
```

Luego agregaría los eventos de más y menos

```
$("html").on("click", "button[name='menos']", function(){
        let numero = Number.parseInt($(this).parent().parent().find("input[name='contador']").val());
        $(this).parent().parent().find("input[name='contador']").val(numero - 1);
    });

    $("html").on("click", "button[name='mas']", function(){
        let numero = Number.parseInt($(this).parent().parent().find("input[name='contador']").val());
        $(this).parent().parent().find("input[name='contador']").val(numero + 1);
    });
```

```js
$("html").on("click", "button[name='menos']", function(){
        let numero = Number.parseInt($(this).parent().parent().find("input[name='contador']").val());
        $(this).parent().parent().find("input[name='contador']").val(numero - 1);
    });

    $("html").on("click", "button[name='mas']", function(){
        let numero = Number.parseInt($(this).parent().parent().find("input[name='contador']").val());
        $(this).parent().parent().find("input[name='contador']").val(numero + 1);
    });

    $("#Agregar").on("click", function(){

        $("#contenedor").append(`
        <div>
        <span class="input-group-btn">
          <button class="btn btn-default" name="menos" type="button">-</button>
        </span>

        <input type="text" name="contador" value="1" min="1"/>

        <span class="input-group-btn">
          <button class="btn btn-default" name="mas" type="button">+</button>
        </span>
        </div>`);
    });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

    <button type="button" id="Agregar">Agregar</button>
    <div id="contenedor">
    </div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

La lógica está bien, solo te faltaria enviar con parentElement

Javascript

```
document.addEventListener('click', e => {
    if (e.target.classList.contains('sumar')) {
        sumar(e.target.parentElement);//esto enviara el codigo html puro a js
    }
    if (e.target.classList.contains('restar')) {
        restar(e.target.parentElement);//esto enviara el codigo html puro a js
    }
}
```

HTML

```
<span class="input-group-btn">
  <button class="btn btn-default restar" id="menos" type="button">-</button>
</span>
<span class="input-group-btn">
  <button class="btn btn-default sumar" id="mas" type="button">+</button>
</span>
```

Script

```
function sumar(element){
  var contador = document.getElementById("contador");
  contador.value = Number(contador.value) + 1
}
function sumar(element){
   var contador = document.getElementById("contador");
   contador.value = Number(contador.value) - 1
}
```